# How to draw an X axis on a barplot?

Tags: r

I am trying to make the simplest barplot in r and cannot get the x axis to show. I'm not trying to add labels or anything fancy, I literally just want a 
black line to be there.

I have tried "`axis.lty=1`", `xaxt`, `lty`, `axes.lty` and none of it has helped. What am I doing wrong?

```
plantmeans<-c(802,1273,468,1286)
barplot(plantmeans,xlab = "Treatment", ylab = "Time taken to unfurl/secs",axis.lty=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
plot1<-barplot(plantmeans,xlab = "Treatment", ylab = "Time taken to unfurl/secs",axis.lty=4)
axis(1,at=plot1,labels=plantmeans)
```

Comment: Just beat me to it.

Comment: ...or possibly `names.arg = rep("",4)` in the `barplot()` call. (Under the assumption the OP doesn't actually want any tick labels.)

Comment: Awesome! You can accept an answer by clicking on the tick just next to it.